# Effect of near zero temperature in ac transformer

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, electric-circuits, superconductivity, electronics

Would there be any variation in the usual ac transformer behavior if one of the coils (namely, the primary coil) - or both - was made of a superconducting material (i.e: lead) and cooled to near zero temperature? If there was, then how would it be?

Also, if I were to make an experiment (assuming that it does have an effect), would liquid nitrogen suffice, or would we rather need liquid hydrogen?

Thanks!

Comment: A crucial thing is (citation needed) that superconductors prefer DC. As far as I remember there are problems with AC, so it isn't used. Take this with a grain of salt, as it is a vague memory, and I couldn't find a reference right away.

Answer (score 0):

There wouldn't be any dramatic effect. It would just make the transformer a bit more efficient.

The effect of resistance in the coils of a transformer is just to dissipate some energy as heat, and since this energy is lost it reduces the efficiency of the transformer. Reducing the coil resistance reduces the energy lost and increases the efficiency. However note that even with superconducting coils the efficiency will not be 100% as there will still be losses in the transformer core.

For most superconductors liquid nitrogen is not cold enough to make them superconducting. For example the superconducting transition temperature of lead is around 7.2K and this is far below the 77K boiling point of liquid nitrogen. You will need liquid helium to do your experiment.

Liquid nitrogen will decrease the coil resistance because the resistance of metals generally falls with decreasing temperature - the resistance just won't fall completely to zero.

There are materials that [are superconductors at the boiling point of liquid nitrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-temperature_superconductivity), but I believe there remain unsolved practical problems with making 
transformers from these materials.